# Popover segue to static cell UITableView causes compile error

Tags: xcode, ios5, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

I currently have an application with two view controllers. The first is a view controller with an embedded table view that has dynamic cells. The second is a table view controller with static cells. If I add a segue from selecting one of the dynamic table's cells to the static table view controller (using the Push or Modal style setting), I can see that the segue works as expected. However, when I change the style to Popover I get the following compile error:

```
Couldn't compile connection: <IBCocoaTouchOutletConnection:0x4004c75a0 <IBProxyObject: 0x400647960> => anchorView => <IBUITableViewCell: 0x400f58aa0>>
```

Has anyone else ran into this issue, or does anyone know what this error message might mean? It seems strange that this is happening at compile time unless a static table view controller is not supported in a Popover...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. You can't hook it up from the storyboard but can do it programmatically like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad"
                                                 bundle:nil];
    UITableViewController *detailController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableSettingDetails"];

    self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:detailController];

    self.popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 416);
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:cell.bounds inView:cell.contentView
                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                          animated:YES];
}
```

Just make sure that you have a reference to your popover in your controller, otherwise it will get immediately disposed - causing some other interesting exceptions.

Comment: As much as I would prefer this to happen in the storyboard (IB) this worked a treat for me, thanks!

Comment: Upvoted as very useful, but is no longer valid in iOS 10 - I've added the relevant iOS 10 code as a separate answer, but if you want to incorporate it into the accepted answer, @lehn0058, go ahead, and I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have to choose an anchor point for that Popover that is NOT the static cell.  My suggestion is to put a UIButton set to be invisible (Custom type).  Then select the Popover Segue and drag the Anchor connection to that button.

Comment: The anchor point for the popover is one of the dynamic cells. Tapping that cell is what brings up the popover with the static cell table.

Comment: I do see that adding a button to the main view and setting that as the anchor gets rid of the compile error, but then my popover doesn't point to the correct cell in the table. Moving the button to the cell causes the same compile error again.

Comment: At this time, you cannot anchor a popover to a static table view cell.

Comment: Again, not trying to anchor it to a static table view cell. Trying to do it to a dynamic one. Apple does this in their iPad version of the Reminders app.

Comment: Or follow my link in the answer below. I do just this and give an example.

Answer (score 0):

I know this one is already answered, but just incase it is helpful I have a solution for this while preserving the storyboard flow using segues. You can check it out here
[Is it possible to perform a Popover Segue manually (from dynamic UITableView cell)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845508/is-it-possible-to-perform-a-popover-segue-manually-from-dynamic-uitableview-cel/14514837#14514837)

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 10, @lehn0058's correct and accepted answer no longer works. Here's his solution updated for iOS 10...

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // *** Next line doesn't work with popover, only full screen detail
    //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "editRow", sender: self) 
    // Hence, do it by hand...
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let detailVC: MyDetailViewController = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "itemEditor") as! MyDetalViewController
    detailVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    detailVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    detailVC.detailItem = self.itemAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    self.present(detailVC, animated: true, completion: {})
}
```