# Swift/iOS 9: using Popover Presentation with a UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, ios9, popover, uipopover

I keep getting this error because I cannot correctly anchor my segue. I've tried a mixture of using Storyboards and coding.

[image]
[image]

I'm a newbie to iOS, so I've been unsuccessfully trying to solve this problem by looking at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229243/popover-segue-to-static-cell-uitableview-causes-compile-error), as well as Youtube videos. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: Can you send me your file? I seem to have different color settings. :)

Comment: Sorry I had this for a long time and don't remember where I got it. These are some alternatives if you like any of these: https://github.com/hdoria/xcode-themes

Comment: Love your theme ! ps: if the question is answered, please accept an answer.

Comment: @blablabla I ended up using different code because the project was due months before I received an answer but sure I'll accept an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience it is easier to just do this programatically and forget about the segue / storyboard all together.

This works in swift 2.0

```
func showPopOverBox(button:UIButton) {
    let popoverViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yourviewcontrollerstoryboardId") as UIViewController!
    popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    popoverViewController.preferredContentSize   = CGSizeMake(600, 600)

    let popoverPresentationViewController = popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController

    popoverPresentationViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any
    popoverPresentationViewController?.sourceView = button
    popoverPresentationViewController?.sourceRect = button.bounds

    presentViewController(popoverViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Swift 3.0 answer:

```
    func showPopOverBox(button:UIButton) 
    {
        let popoverViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourviewcontrollerstoryboardId")   UIViewController!
        popoverViewController?.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        popoverViewController?.preferredContentSize = CGSize.init(width: 600, height: 600)

        let popoverPresentationViewController = popoverViewController?.popoverPresentationController

        popoverPresentationViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.up
        popoverPresentationViewController?.sourceView = button
        popoverPresentationViewController?.sourceRect = button.bounds

        present(popoverViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```